# Plot every 10 datapoint in a vector by different color in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I have one dimensional vector in R which I would like to plot like :
[image: this]
Every 10 data points have different color. How do I do this in R with normal `plot` function, with `ggplot` and with `plotly`?

Comment: please add some data to repdroduce the shown plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `ggplot` solution; unfortunately you don't provide sample data, so I'm generating some random data.

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 0.001 * 1:100 + runif(1000));

# The number of different colours
nCol <- 5;
df$col <- rep(1:nCol, each = 10);

# ggplot
library(tidyverse);
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = as.factor(col), group = 1)) +
    geom_line();
```

[image]

For `plotly` just wrap the `ggplot` call within `ggplotly`.

Answer (score 3):

in base `R` you can try this.

I changed the data a little bit compared to the other answer

```
# The data
set.seed(2017);
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 0.001 * 1:100 + runif(100));
nCol <- 10;
df$col <- rep(1:10, each = 10);

# base R plot
plot(df[1:2]) #add `type="n"` to remove the points
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) lines(df[x+0:1,1:2], col=df$col[x], lwd=2))
```

[image]

As for lines the `col` parameter will be recycled you have to use a loop (here `sapply`) over the rows and plot segments.

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't show you how to do it in a specific plotting package, but instead shows how to assign random colors to your data according to your specifications. The benefit of this approach is that it gives you control over which colors you use if you choose.

```
library(dplyr) # assumed okay given ggplot2 mention
df = data_frame(v1=rnorm(100))
n = nrow(df)
df$group = (1:n - (1:n %% -10)) / 10
colors = sample(colors(), max(df$group), replace=FALSE)
df$color = colors[df$group]
df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(row_number() <= 2) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 20 x 3
              v1 group           color
           <dbl> <dbl>           <chr>
 1 -0.6941434087     1 lightsteelblue2
 2 -0.4559695973     1 lightsteelblue2
 3  0.7567737300     2  darkgoldenrod2
 4  0.9478937275     2  darkgoldenrod2
 5 -1.2358486079     3      slategray3
 6 -0.7068140340     3      slategray3
 7  1.3625895045     4        cornsilk
 8 -2.0416315923     4        cornsilk
 9 -0.6273386846     5  darkgoldenrod4
10 -0.5884521130     5  darkgoldenrod4
11  0.0645078975     6   antiquewhite1
12  1.3176727205     6   antiquewhite1
13 -1.9082708004     7           khaki
14  0.2898018693     7           khaki
15  0.7276799336     8     greenyellow
16  0.2601492048     8     greenyellow
17 -0.0514811315     9       seagreen1
18  0.8122600269     9       seagreen1
19  0.0004641533    10   darkseagreen4
20 -0.9032770589    10   darkseagreen4
```

The above code first creates a fake dataset with 100 rows of data, and sets `n` equal to 100. `df$group` is set by taking the row numbers (`1:n`) performing a rather convoluted evaluation to get a vector of numbers like `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, ..., 10)`. It then samples the colors available in base R returning as many colors as their are groups (`max(df$group)`) and then using the `group` variable to index the `color` vector to get the color. The final output is just the first two rows of each group to show that the colors are the same within group, but different between groups. This should now be able to be passed in as a variable in your various plotting environments.